# DNS Record - Change Current Ownership using PowerShell

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, powershell

In DNS I have some computers in the list where the current owner no longer exists, so you see the SID info as the Current Owner. I like to change this to the machine_name$.

Anyone know how to do this via PowerShell? You can only change to user/group using AD.
I have used the Add-QADPermission cmd but this does not change the ownership and have not been able to find anything that could. Thanks in advance

Comment: After reading more I found the best way to do this was set the owner using the SID. Adding to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import-Module D:\Powershell\DNS\DnsShell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

# Retrieve records
$servers = get-content D:\Powershell\Scripts\DNSRECORDS.txt
$newarray = @()
foreach ($computer in $servers) {
    Get-ADDnsPartition | Get-ADDnsRecord | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Computer} | % {
        $RecordName = $_.Name
        $RecordName = "GTLAW\$RecordName" + '$'
        $RecordDN = (Get-ADObject –Identity $_.ObjectGUID).DistinguishedName
        $Owner = (Get-Acl -Path "ActiveDirectory:://RootDSE/$RecordDN").Owner
        If ($Owner -eq "$RecordName") {
            Write-Host 'Good |' $_.Name '|' $Owner
        } Else {    
            Write-Host 'Bad |' $_.Name '|' $RecordName $Owner 
            $AdACL = get-ACL ("AD:\" + $RecordDN)
            $ADobject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($_.NAME + "$")
            $sid = $ADobject.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
            $AdACL.SetOwner($sid)
            set-acl -path ("AD:\" + $RecordDN) -AclObject $AdACL
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `<br/>` tag for code. There's a code button `{}` that will preserve formatting and linebreaks. I'd normally edit this myself, but there are a billion linebreaks.

Comment: TY - I could not see it correctly and why I added them. It was like it ignored the newlines

Comment: Here are the download links of the dependencies of this script: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dnsshell and https://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Quest_ActiveRoles_Management_Shell_Download

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to use any third party modules.  This script will go through all the zones (with conditions) and set every DNS Resource Record (with conditions) to the owner that you specify so long as it is currently owned by the list of Bad Owners.

```
$Cred=Get-Credential -Message "Input Domain ADMIN credentials" -UserName "<username>"

#This command automatically loads the AD module and allows the path "AD:\" to exist
$DNSServer=(Get-ADDomain).PDCEmulator
$CimSession=New-CimSession -ComputerName $DNSServer -Credential $Cred

$Owner=Get-ADUser -Identity "<name of account of owner you want to use>"
$SID=[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($Owner.SID.Value)
$BadOwners=@(<list of owners that you want to replace>)

#Customize this next line to your needs
$ZoneNames=Get-DnsServerZone -CimSession $CimSession -ComputerName $DNSServer | Where-Object { ($_.ZoneType -eq "Primary") -and !$_.IsAutoCreated -and $_.IsDsIntegrated -and !$_.IsReverseLookupZone -and ($_.ZoneName -ne "TrustAnchors") }
$ZoneNames=@($ZoneNames)
for ($i=0; $i -lt $ZoneNames.Count; $i++) {
  # The TimeStamp condition at the end of this line ensures that static records will not be modified.
  $DNSRecord=Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -CimSession $CimSession -RRType A -ComputerName $DNSServer -ZoneName $ZoneNames[$i].ZoneName | Where-Object { ($_.HostName -ne "@") -and (!$_.HostName.Contains(".")) -and ($_.TimeStamp -ne $null) }
  $DNSRecord=@($DNSRecord)
  for ($j=0; $j -lt $DNSRecord.Count; $j++) {
    $ACL=Get-Acl -Path "AD:\$($DNSRecord[$j].DistinguishedName)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($ACL -ne $null) {
      if ($ACL.Owner -in $BadOwners) {
        Write-Verbose "Processing $($DNSRecord[$j].DistinguishedName)"
        $ACL.SetOwner($SID) 
        $ACL | Set-Acl -Path "AD:\$($DNSRecord[$j].DistinguishedName)"
      }
    }
    else {
      Write-Warning "$($DNSRecord[$j].DistinguishedName) ACL was NULL"
       }
  }
}
Remove-CimSession -CimSession $CimSession
```